# VBA Copy Paste without formatting from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste, paste

I have this code which helps me to copy paste information from one workbook to another. The values get pasted with format and formulas, but I want to paste them as simple text. I have tried to add the `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` but I get an error saying `Compile Error: Expected: end of statement`.

```
Sub get_data()
 
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
 
'Dont update screen, works faster.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
'Open Workbook. Input FULL path inside quotation marks, including extension of the file.
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("wocnewoi.xlsm")
 
'Data gets filled with the following code:
 
'Information
Wb1.Worksheets("Info").Range("G14").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Information").Range("C6")
    
Wb1.Worksheets("Info").Range("G16").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Information").Range("C8")

Wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a value directly to a cell is more efficient than using `Copy/PasteSpecial`.

Please try.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Information").Range("C6").Value = _
        Wb1.Worksheets("Info").Range("G14").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Information").Range("C8").Value = _
        Wb1.Worksheets("Info").Range("G16").Value
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you so much! One more question, how do I paste the values with certain formatting? The other workbook has different formatting for different worksheets. I just want to standardize the formatting on the new workbook.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `certain formatting`.

Comment: Some words are bold and italic, other words are underlined and blue, etc.

Comment: Here comes all possible paste options.

_Microsoft documentation:_

> [XlPasteType enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: "values get pasted with format and formulas, but I want to paste them as simple text" and "how do I paste the values with certain formatting?" don't seem to be consistent, so it seems like your actual needs are different from the explanation in your question?